# Fatal error on production server, staging is OK

Tags: php, codeigniter

I fix a web application based on CodeIgniter framework. I stumbled upon with strange error when I established the app on production server.

> Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in /path/to/app/application/controllers/user.php on line 77

On that line I have this function:

```
public function update_user_movement(){
        if (empty($this->input->post())){ // Line 77
            redirect('user/movement','location');
        }
        // other code
}
```

As I mentioned in title I don't receive any error on staging server. Why is that?

Edit: I don't agree that this question is duplicate, because in other question CodeIgniter is not mentioned, and I think this problem is connected to it.

Comment: Also, there is a big note in [the manual](http://www.php.net/empty) about this: `Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else will result in a parse error...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably different server configurations (if you're sure the files are identical). To fix it, do something like this:

```
public function update_user_movement(){
        $post = $this->input->post();
        if (empty($post)){ // Line 77
            redirect('user/movement','location');
        }
        // other code
}
```

Comment: It'd probably be something to do with PHP versioning, but this answer is exactly what you'd need.